# What is a word that means "starting from one"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, mathematics

I'm looking for an adjective that means "to start from the number one."

This is so I can describe a sequence that starts from the number one. I want to be able to say something like "Choose any [adj] sequence" where [adj] is the adjective in this question.

I know there aren't always words that exist for every combination of words, but can anyone think of a word that might work for this?

Comment: At first I thought of a "positive" sequence of integers, but that doesn't necessarily start at 1. Do you mean in particular the sequences (1, 2, 3 ... n) where n is a positive integer? Or any old sequence that starts with 1? (In which latter case (1, -1, -3 ...) is valid.)

Comment: I'm using the mathematical definition of a sequence so (1, 2, 3, ..., n) where n is a positive integer, (1, 3, 4), and (1, -2, -5) are all valid.

Comment: In that case, I might say "starts with the number one" instead of "from the number one".

Comment: Since the numbers in a sequence are all in an order, I think "starts from the number one" makes sense.

Comment: Adam, out of curiosity, is there a name for the sequences (1, 2, 3, ..., n) where n is a positive integer?

Answer (score 1):

Given your clarification above, I don't believe that there is a single word to convey the property of beginning with 1 in such a general sense.

In a math context I would use "Choose any natural sequence *having 1 as its first element*" or "Choose any natural sequence *that starts with 1*."

Of course if this is a mathematics paper or assignment, it is perfectly acceptable to define a new term. Eg.: "Definition. A sequence of natural numbers is said to be *one-grounded* if it begins with 1." After which you can use the new term without fear of ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

A numbering or indexing system that starts from 1 is said to be *one-based*. By contrast, most of the widely used programming languages are *zero-based*.

See, for example, [this article](http://www.biostars.org/p/6373/).

Comment: I think your suggestion is true for numbering or indexing systems but may not be understood/may have different connotations based on the context it's in which it's used and therefore doesn't mean starting from one in the general sense. For example, if I said "Choose any one-based sequence," it its only meaning "choose a sequence that starts from one"? Couldn't one take that to mean "choose any sequence that increments by one"?

Comment: I think "one-based" would imply only sequences like (1, 2, 3, ... n).

Comment: @AdamBrown To quote from the OP's question: "This is so I can describe a sequence that starts from the number one."

Comment: @Gnawme - Well, sure. (1, -10, 100, ...) is also a sequence that starts from one, but it strikes me as not suggested by "one-based".

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought "cardinal sequence" would work, but the mathematicians seem to have co-opted the term to mean something different.

Comment: Not sure I see your point. A cardinal number is defined as "any of the numbers that express amount" so a cardinal sequence would be "any of the sequences that express amount". Is there another definition of cardinal you're referring to?

Comment: Cardinal as in a number used in counting. Wolfram says "In common usage, a cardinal number is a number used in counting (a counting number), such as 1, 2, 3, ....".